# Build static library in monotouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to build a static library using **MonoTouch** that can be used by Xcode developers?  What about the headers?

I come from a C# background and I have a large library to port over to iOS.

It'd save me oodles of time if I could keep it in C# and adjust as needed.

Comment: It is easy to go the other way (call Obj-C from C#), but I would think it would be difficult to call C# from Obj-C. I just would just go *all* MonoTouch, but I don't know all the business details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible. See here:

[MonoTouch: talking from Obj-C to MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472993/monotouch-talking-from-obj-c-to-monotouch)

Which links to a project that *tries* to do what you want:

http://www.guidebee.biz/forum/redirect.php?fid=16&tid=176&goto=nextoldset