# MonoTouch --keeptemp output

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I try to figure out how I could get the main.m template and other code from MonoTouch when i compile my project with the additional mtouch arguments `-v -v -v --keeptemp`. 
This is suggested in older posts [MonoTouch: talking from Obj-C to MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472993/monotouch-talking-from-obj-c-to-monotouch/5481074#5481074)  but I can't see any output (.m or .s files)

I use MonoDevelop 3.0.6 with MonoTouch version 6.0.8 (no evaluation version)

I don't use a command line tool. In MonoDevelop i add my arguments in the "Iphone Build/ Additional mtouch arguments:" project options.

I try to compile the AVCaptureFrames from the MonoTouch examples. There is already this additional argument in the Release configuration `-v -v -v -keeptemp` (Only with one `-`!)

I tried it with `-keeptemp` and with `--keeptemp` but get no additional .m or .s files generated. (Or don't aware where they located)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-keeptemp` means the `mtouch` (command-line) tool won't delete the temporary files it creates. However it does not change where those files are created, i.e. they are still created in a temporary directory.

Now to locate the temporary directory that was used you'll need to check your build logs (inside MonoDevelop's Error Pad List) and look at the file being used.

E.g. find `main.m` in the logs and you'll see the directory where it was (created and then) used. You can open the file from that location (if `-keeptemp` was used, otherwise it's deleted).

Comment: Thanks for the info. This makes it clear. In my case the main.m seems to have the name main.armv7.m .